# how can we disable a column in one view and enable in another view of a particular custom list in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i have a requirement of disable one particular column(i.e category) in a list of view(allitems),

here iam having two views(allitems,admin) of a particular list..
so now i wants to disable that column in "allitems" view and enable in "admin view"

can anyone get me out of this problem

thanks in advance,
naresh

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean disable column on a view? I guess you are looking to disable column when a user clicks and get onto either Display or Edit Form? All columns by default are read-only, the only columns that have associations appears as hyperlinks - Title (linked to item) etc and lookup columns.

Comment: I mean that i have created 2 views(allitems.aspx,adminview.aspx),so here when a user inserts items by clicking new item link...the column "category" has to disable to the users and that will be enable in adminview.aspx page(this page for admin users)

Comment: So you have "category" for which the value is entered by the user. I am assuming, it is a normal text field. When user comes onto AdminView.aspx (your view), he sees multiple list items (if there are) and one of the columns is category. By default it must be a normal non-editable field. You can hide that field by not adding it to your AllItems.aspx throw view settings, so that it doesn't show up on AllItems.aspx?

Comment: yeah i did that mr.nitin,but my requirement is like "category" will not be select by user in allitems.aspx page....but that column has to be select by admin users in adminview.aspx page when admin wants to add a item

Comment: So do you mean to say "category" cannot be added by anyone other than non-admin and that this is done during data entry. If this is true, you have to frame your question correctly for people to be able to help you.

Comment: yeah Mr.Nitin..thats correct...i vl modify my question as u said

Comment: I have done the same thing using custom rendering templates (one of the ways of  customizing list forms). They give you the flexibility to do whatever you want. Another way could be one over here - http://srikanthsharepointmcp.blogspot.com/2010/05/hide-or-disable-field-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: Another possible option for you - http://www.sharepointclowns.com/2011/06/hide-a-column-on-new-or-edit-form-in-sharepoint-using-jquery/ Instead of hide you can disable with some default value if you want.

Comment: hi mr.nitin,i have followed the link and changed in editform.aspx..but my field is not disabled...can you tell me where iam wrong